# Create index with completion suggest using Nest elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, completion

I am using elasticsearc 2.3.3 and Nest 2.3.2, I need to create index. Need to map the properties with attributes added in the class file.

```
public class IndexDocument
{
    [Number(Store = true)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [String(Store = true, Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, TermVector = TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Attachment File { get; set; }
    [String(Store = true, Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)]
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    [String(Store = true, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string DocLocation { get; set; }
    [String(Store = true, Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)]
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }

}

public class Attachment
{
    public Attachment()
    {

    }
    [String(Name = "_content_length", Store = true, Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)]
    public long ContentLength { get; set; }
    [String(Store = true, Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, TermVector = TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets, Name = "_content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

}
```

Also I would like to add a **completion suggest** to the **File** field.
I am new in this elastic search. Can anyone please help?

I have created my attachment index as below. How to append completion suggest and stemmer code with this?

```
this.client.CreateIndex("mydocs", c => c.Mappings(mp => mp.Map<IndexDocument>
                (m => m.Properties(ps => ps.Attachment
                        (a => a.Name(o => o.File)
                               .TitleField(t => t.Name(x => x.Title).TermVector(TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets))
                               )))));
```

Comment: How is `Attachment` mapped? As `object`, as `attachment`?

Comment: @RussCam   This is my create index code.  this.client.CreateIndex("mydocs", c => c.Mappings(mp => mp.Map<IndexDocument>
                    (m => m.Properties(ps => ps.Attachment
                            (a => a.Name(o => o.File)
                                   .TitleField(t => t.Name(x => x.Title).TermVector(TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets))
                                   )))));

Comment: @RussCam : Even I'm looking out for this. **1.** How can I add the completion suggester to an attachement(on fields content and title)? **2.** And also can we use multiple analyzers on the same field? because I'm already using english analyzer on my content so that it will look for all the possibilities(like if i search for property, it will check for properties etc ) of the search term and then generate results. I want to add auto complete alongside english analyzer. Is it possible to do so?? TIA

Comment: @ASN please either add your questions as new questions here on StackOverflow or on https://discuss.elastic.co/

Comment: @RussCam ok sure. I just thought it is similar to this question so asked here. Anyways will add a new question on SO. Thanks.

Comment: @AjA Did you manage to find a solution to this? Adding a completion suggester when indexing the document?